# Cabal build failure on ReadArgs when deploying to OpenShift

Tags: haskell, openshift, cabal, yesod

I am trying to deploy a web application to OpenShift. My app is written with [Yesod web framework](http://www.yesodweb.com/). I would like to use the Yesod cartridge from [Haskell wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Web/Cloud).

I can create the application and deploy the example supplied with the cartridge. However, when I add more dependencies to the cabal file, the build after pushing fails.

An example of failing dependency is `ReadArgs`. It fails with the following error:

```
remote: ReadArgs.hs:11:8:
remote:     Could not find module `Filesystem.Path'
remote:     There are files missing in the `system-filepath-0.4.12' package,
remote:     try running 'ghc-pkg check'.
remote:     Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
remote:
remote: ReadArgs.hs:12:8:
remote:     Could not find module `Filesystem.Path.CurrentOS'
remote:     There are files missing in the `system-filepath-0.4.12' package,
remote:     try running 'ghc-pkg check'.
remote:     Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

The `ghc-pkg check` command says following about `system-filepath`:

```
There are problems in package system-filepath-0.4.12:
  Warning: library-dirs: /var/lib/openshift/52a44a9e4382ecf07100007e/app-root/data/workspace/Haskell-Cloud/usr/lib/system-filepath-0.4.12/ghc-7.8.4 doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  Warning: haddock-interfaces: /var/lib/openshift/52a44a9e4382ecf07100007e/app-root/data/workspace/Haskell-Cloud/usr/share/doc/system-filepath-0.4.12/html/system-filepath.haddock doesn't exist or isn't a file
  Warning: haddock-html: /var/lib/openshift/52a44a9e4382ecf07100007e/app-root/data/workspace/Haskell-Cloud/usr/share/doc/system-filepath-0.4.12/html doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  import-dirs: /var/lib/openshift/52a44a9e4382ecf07100007e/app-root/data/workspace/Haskell-Cloud/usr/lib/system-filepath-0.4.12/ghc-7.8.4 doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  cannot find any of ["Filesystem/Path.hi","Filesystem/Path.p_hi","Filesystem/Path.dyn_hi"]
  cannot find any of ["Filesystem/Path/CurrentOS.hi","Filesystem/Path/CurrentOS.p_hi","Filesystem/Path/CurrentOS.dyn_hi"]
  cannot find any of ["Filesystem/Path/Rules.hi","Filesystem/Path/Rules.p_hi","Filesystem/Path/Rules.dyn_hi"]
  cannot find any of ["Filesystem/Path/Internal.hi","Filesystem/Path/Internal.p_hi","Filesystem/Path/Internal.dyn_hi"]
  cannot find any of ["libHSsystem-filepath-0.4.12.a","libHSsystem-filepath-0.4.12.p_a","libHSsystem-filepath-0.4.12-ghc7.8.4.so","libHSsystem-filepath-0.4.12-ghc7.8.4.dylib","HSsystem-filepath-0.4.12-ghc7.8.4.dll"] on library path
```

These seem like serious problems, however it does not tell me how to fix it.

How can I find out why the build fails? How can I get it to build?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out this was a bug in the cartridge and is fixed now.

It used to be [issue #3](https://bitbucket.org/accursoft/haskell-cloud/issues/3/failed-to-install-packages-depending-on), but the issue tracker seems to have been erased since.